# Smooks - Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

Tags: java, maven, smooks

Currently, I am working with Smooks (1.5 version). In my last step, I changed names of packages in my project and the following error has been raised:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
>   (default-cli) on project JavaBindings: Command execution failed.
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

There is my POM.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>SmooksConversion</name>
    <groupId>org.smooksservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaBindings</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <smooks.version>1.4</smooks.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-javabean</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-json</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-edi</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-templating</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${smooks.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus.m2.snapshots</id>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a stack trace of this?

Comment: You should probably show the part where you invoke the exec-maven plugin.

Comment: Run maven in debug mode: the error message you have quoted only reveals that an external process has exited with a non zero status, but that's all.

Comment: --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ JavaBindings --- Error: Could not find or load main class _07_templating.Run. It is old name of my pkg, but i dont know where to find it

Comment: try to Clean and Build the project

Comment: When i click "Clean and Build" then :BUILD SUCCESS, But if i click run there appear an error(Could not find or load main class _07_templating.Run)

Comment: I would clean maven repository but not sure if it is going to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this plugin to your pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>...</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I added this plugin and still this same error. I found in log: --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ JavaBindings ---
Error: Could not find or load main class _07_templating.Run. It is old name of my pkg, but i dont know where to find it/

Comment: did you put the full path(package and class name) here
<mainClass> </mainClass>
?

Comment: Yes i did, it looks like this -> <mainClass>conv.Run</mainClass>